# Wrong title for every module on website

Tags: magento2

Magento 2 show wrong title for every module on website, example module warranty and payment (Create new customer account). It show for title path vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/title.phtml

How i can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed setting the title in my custom modules, at \Vendor\Module\Controller\Index, per example.

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
 */
protected $_resultPageFactory;

/**
 * @param Context $context, 
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
 */
public function __construct(Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
{
    $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
 * return page factory
 */
public function execute()
{
    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('My Module Title'));
    return $resultPage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that you don't have an extension adding a block into the customer area that extends from the Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History block. This block sets the page title in the constructor. I have seen an extension that did this and several account sections then had the page title of "My Orders".